# TypeScript Generic Type with modified key names from another type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Let's say I have an interface

```
interface Foo {
   id: string;
   bar: string;
}

interface Person {
   name: string;
   age: number;
   birthdate: Date;
   active: boolean;
   foo: Foo;
}
```

I want to be able to create an interface with the names of the first interface but concatenated with another string. So given the Generic type `FilterFor`, can I create a generic type

```
type FilterFor<T> = ...
```

Such that calling `FilterFor<Person>` would produce the following interface:

```
interface FilterForPerson {
    name: string;
    name__in: string[];
    name__search: string;
    age: number;
    age__gt: number;
    age__gte: number;
    age__lt: number;
    age__lte: number;
    birthdate: Date;
    birthdate__gt: Date;
    birthdate__gte: Date;
    birthdate__lt: Date;
    birthdate__lte: Date;
    foo: string|Foo
    foo__in: Array<string|Foo>
    active: boolean
}
```

edit: Added `date`,`foo`, `active` fields

Comment: Here's a slightly different approach that has type `string[]` instead of `string` for `name__in`: https://tsplay.dev/m3VaEN

Comment: I've updated the question to include date, boolean, and object fields

Comment: @jcalz Feel free to post the answer.

Comment: Please thoroughly review [this version](https://tsplay.dev/WKK7ZW); if it meets your needs I'll write it up as an answer... if not, what remains?  You might want to check several different use cases before responding, there's no rush on my end.

Comment: Looks good except one revision: for `string` types it should be `[`${K}__in`, string[]]` not `[`${K}__in`, string]` as `__in` accepts an array of strings

Comment: Oh yeah that was essentially a typo on my part.  I'll fix it when I write up the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various possible ways to implement this.  The solution I present here involves [key-remapping in mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) which lets you transform both the keys and the values of your input type.  We'll first calculate an intermediate type called `Fields<T>` which turns your input type `T` into a big [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of key-value [tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types), and then we'll make `FilterFor<T>` over the results of that to get the final type.  (Thanks to [@Oblosys](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5770132/oblosys) for this approach).

So `Fields<{a: string, b: number}>` would be something like `["a", string] | ["a__search", string] | ["a__in", string[]] | ["b", number] | ["b__gt", number] | ⋯`, and then `FilterFor<{a: string, b: number}>` would map over `Fields<{a: string, b: number}>` to give `{a: string, a__search: string, a__in: string[], b: number, b__gt: number, ⋯ }`.

---

Here's how I'd write `Fields<T>`:

```
type Fields<T> = { [K in string & keyof T]:
  T[K] extends number | Date ? [K | `${K}__${"gt" | "gte" | "lt" | "lte"}`, T[K]] :
  T[K] extends object ? [K, string | T[K]] | [`${K}__in`, (string | T[K])[]] :
  T[K] extends string ? [K | `${K}__search`, string] | [`${K}__in`, string[]] :
  [K, T[K]]
}[string & keyof T]
```

This is a *distributive object type* of the form `{[K in KK]: F<K>}[KK]`, which ends up computing a union of `F<K>` for every `K` in the `KK` union.  In the above, `KK` is `string & keyof T`, or just the `string`-typed keys of the input type `T` (this excludes `number` keys and `symbol` keys if they exist). And `F<K>` is a series of [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) that make the right key-value tuples for `K`.

The particular rules I'm following are... first check the value type `T[K]` of the property of `T` at key `K`.

- If it's `number` or `Date`, then we want a bunch of keys including `K` and a [template-literal-type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types) concatenation of `K` with the various comparison suffixes, and the value type is left alone.
- Otherwise, if it's an `object` (and note that `Date` is an `object` so we need to do it in this order), then we want to keep the key `K` and value `T[K]` unioned with `string`, and we also want the key `K` with an  `__in` suffix and a value of an *array* of `T[K]`-unioned-with-`string`.
- Otherwise, if it's `string`, then we want `K` and `K`-with-a-`__search` suffix to have a `string` value, and `K`-with-an-`__in` suffix to have a `string[]` value.
- Otherwise, just leave the key `K` and value `T[K]` as-is.

Once we do that, `FilterFor<T>` is simply:

```
type FilterFor<T> = { [F in Fields<T> as F[0]]: F[1] }
```

which just maps over each entry in `Field<T>` using the first element `as` the key, and the second element as the value.

---

Okay, let's test it:

```
interface Foo {
  id: string;
  bar: string;
}

interface Person {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  birthdate: Date;
  active: boolean;
  foo: Foo;
}

type FilterForPerson = FilterFor<Person>
/* type FilterForPerson = {
    name: string;
    name__search: string;
    name__in: string[];
    age: number;
    age__gt: number;
    age__gte: number;
    age__lt: number;
    age__lte: number;
    birthdate: Date;
    birthdate__gt: Date;
    birthdate__gte: Date;
    birthdate__lt: Date;
    birthdate__lte: Date;
    active: boolean;
    foo: string | Foo;
    foo__in: (string | Foo)[];
} */
```

Looks good!  The `age` and `birthdate` properties get the `number`-or-`Date` treatment, while the `foo` property gets the non-`Date`-`object` treatment, the `name` property gets the `string` treatment, and `active` gets the everything-else treatment.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&noErrorTruncation=true#code/FDAuE8AcFMAIDECW0A2ATAzgHgCoD5YBeWAb1gG0BpWRAO1g1ACc6BzWAMlgGtpwB7AGawcAXQBcwWCKqjY0AB6hotTLFoBXALYAjaE1gAfWABEAhstgB+CtWMADACQlKAXwD675wCJWob0awvsoBxt4o-oHhIa72ADQylKJyktI4svJKKmr8OgBW0ADGoNa2CYwstOzG6UlyxuROLh7udPGwABQVbIG1ogCU5MmwqYlyisqqGAzMPTZUgU1unhjQZkyFABbt3VX1FEstbeWzVUMpUmVjosCu5LvsXLwCwmIgEDAIiBH68PxMuAIxDI5HgNHoSFQmEBsDM03g5AADMlxAhyABGOSuEB0ZRMQRmQpwP78UiXRBoVEPADclx06ypp1YtOxwFx+gJRNgAAV9Bh+PQSJdaGYtNBGZVmZczKxxeptHomLTpDpEExQJs0BY5eZlMrYcVEAA3OU6fj8FBrWj6wTm1EkllgKDE754v5MXlMfn0YhIH5Md1YT3evDAAD0ACpYB8Xf73cGBUQydJpCKxRK2PrU6LoCs1htNhmqln1DnPHQi6whiWZXLNLp9DXZZ4-Kj64qm7n3H46wrG5dpLXPBE232lQPYc33D9Rw3xynYKr1ZrtajddAS0uNVrlC3QGvtZu1dvtXudYeJ1uV7vp-vTBeF1ed12Z-e9RPCaBjabzZazNaJ1tfhK0CB1APNctaFRLomVA81BlEFlYAjMMgA)